# How to create loading in python shell

Tags: python, python-3.x, cmd

In `pip`, when you install a library and it starts downloading you can see a loading rectangle that start filling with white. How to add something like that in output shell to show a progress?

Comment: https://tqdm.github.io

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for `tqdm`

Installation

```
pip3 install tqdm
```

```
from tqdm import tqdm
for i in tqdm(range(20)):
    pass
```

Output

```
100%|██████████| 20/20 [00:00<00:00, 6686.28it/s]
```

[DOCS](https://pypi.org/project/tqdm/) for more help